# Shopify Webhook not triggering when creating an order through API

Tags: php, api, shopify, webhooks

When I create an order through the orders API the webhook for orders/create does not fire, however, if a real order comes through the store the webhook successfully fires.

Does anyone know how I can use the orders API to create an order and have the webhook trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order hook for shopify triggers every-time, sometimes even multiple times and it triggers for order-update too when order is created.
There must be something wrong that you were trying.

You can use logger to write down to a file with extension ".txt". So that you can know how many times web-hook is triggered or it's triggered or not.

You can use this:
https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog

Answer (score 0):

The webhook is working now even though I changed nothing. It must have been an issue with shopify